# Handling strings inside Files

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to save data from a file into an array but I've had no luck for now. It's easy to save data after it was read from the file in case it's just numbers, but for example if I'm trying to save strings, the program keeps crashing over and over again. I'm using fscanf(); function since the whole .txt file is written in the same format: "First Name, Last Name". Now then, I've tried using the for loop in this way:

```
char *firstName = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*10240);
char *lastName = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*10240);
for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
    fscanf(fp, "%s %s", firstName[i],lastName[i]);
}
```

And that's where it crashes.

Comment: Pick one language: C or C++.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Looks like C, but if it's really C++ consider using fstream

Comment: That code should have caused the compiler to produce warnings, and if not then you need to enable more warnings. The warnings should have made you think a little, like "doesn't the arguments to [`fscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) need to be pointers?" And "if `firstName` is a pointer to `char`, then isn't `firstName[i]` a single `char`?"

Comment: And please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

Pure C code:

You have to allocate the array of arrays first, then allocate each string one by one
It's best to scan the strings into temp strings with a big size, and duplicate the strings later.

```
int i,nb_names = 10;
char **firstName = malloc(sizeof *firstName * nb_names);
char **lastName = malloc(sizeof *lastName *nb_names);
char tempn[1000],templ[1000];
for(i = 0; i<nb_names; i++){
    fscanf(fp,"%s %s", tempn,templ);
    firstName[i] = strdup(tempn);
    lastName[i] = strdup(templ);

}
```

Note that I have changed `for (int i` to `for (i` because it is not C compliant but rather C++ compliant (or C99, not sure).
For C++, drop the mallocs and use `std::vector` and `std:string` instead.

I'd recommend to use C++ if you can. I answered a lot of C/C++ questions on people trying (and failing) to allocate 2D arrays properly (including me 5 minutes ago damn :)). C++ using C++ library code is much clearer.

Full C++ example, reading from standard input

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int nb_names = 10;
vector<string > firstName(nb_names);
vector<string > lastName(nb_names);

for(int i = 0; i<nb_names; i++){

    cin >> firstName[i]; 
    cin >> lastName[i];

}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Right! (it worked but I was lucky). Fixed.

Comment: Suggest `char **firstName = malloc(sizeof *firstName  * nb_names);` to avoid coding errors.

Comment: edited. Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score -1):

The error in your code is : firstName[i] is a character not a string but you use it like a string by using %s instead of %c.

you should use a char ** instead of char *.

char **firstName = (char**)malloc(10*sizeof(char)*10240);

I think also that 10240 is too much for firstName. Use 255 or less.

Comment: That's not going to work very well. A single contiguous array of  102400 bytes is not the same as an array of ten string pointers.

Comment: I agree with you if you use an offset instead of index . In that case you should access like this firstName+offset not firstname[i]

Comment: Offset is updated as much as string is readed

Comment: No need to use `sizeof(char)` since that is 1 by definition.